# How to correctly stream data via Bluetooth to Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, serial-communication, data-stream

I'm in the process of developing an application which reads data from a DAQ that streams its data over Bluetooth. The packet sizes can change, as can the sampling rate (1Hz - 512Hz), and I'm able to loop through and read the data off the device using a buffer.

My question is, how do I correctly process the data when there is such a variable of packet size and sampling rate? How do I determine the buffer size?

Currently I'm simply opening a socket, opening an input stream, and then using a while loop (while the socket is open == true) to read from the stream, and process the data (simple decoding, not an extraneous task).

As an example, there are 23 bytes in a packet, and I have the sampling rate very low at the moment at 1Hz. I have a buffer of 256 bytes, which means that it wont accommodate a full packet at the end of the buffer, and I've written code for it to run over onto the next buffer. Once the data is read grab one packet from the buffer, decode and store it, do the next one, etc.

How should I be streaming, and manipulating the data correctly? Eventually I'll be grabbing something in the region of 44 packets at 512Hz, right at Bluetooths transfer limit, and I want to be able to process it as effective as possible, and display errors when a packet is dropped in the process, etc.

TL;DR: how do I correctly stream data using buffers and/or interrupts.